# MongoDB Map Reduce Showing "[object Object]" as key despite type checking against them

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to use mapReduce in Mongo to count the number of times a count the times a given value shows up.

Here is my map function where I test to make sure every value is a string:

```
function mapFunction () {
    function normalizeDate(date) {
        var day = date.getDay(),
        month = date.getMonth(),
        year = date.getYear();
        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }

    if (this.events.event.toString() === "[object Object]"
       || typeof(this.events.event) !== 'string') {
          throw new Error("Not a string...");
    }

    emit(normalizeDate(this.date), this.events.event);
}
```

Here is my reduce function, for the sake of completeness:

```
function reduceFunction (date, event_arry) {
    return event_arry.reduce(function (a, b) {
    if (a[b]) {
        a[b]++;
    }
    else {
        a[b] = 1;
    }
    return a;
    }, {});
}
```

Then, I run mapReduce in the mongo repl:

```
mongos> db.events.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out: 'mr_test'})
{
    "result" : "mr_test",
    "timeMillis" : 148,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 3481,
        "emit" : 3481,
        "reduce" : 82,
        "output" : 14
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

And there are no errors, suggesting that all of the `event`s were of type `string`.

Yet when I look at the output in the `mr_test` collection I get several entries like this:

```
mongos> db.mr_test.find()
{ "_id" : ISODate("0113-04-05T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "[object Object]" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("0113-04-06T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "[object Object]" : 5 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("0113-04-30T00:00:00Z"), "value" : { "[object Object]" : 1, "eventTypeA" : 9, "eventTypeB" : 14, "eventTypeC" : 19 } }
```

Is there a good explanation for this? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent explanation for this (it's the same thing 99% of all problems with MongoDB mapreduce are.  Your map value is different format than your reduce is returning.

Your reduce function must return the same format that your map function emits.

You are emitting a string and you expect to get back a document!  What you need to do is in your map function emit the exact format you expect at the end:

```
emit(normalizeDate(this.date), {this.events.event:1} );
```

This says: "for a particular day (key) I'm tracking a single event-string and its total is 1".

Then adjust your reduce function to iterate over the values array merging it together keeping in mind that since the reduce function can be called multiple times (to re-reduce results for a particular key) the documents you are "merging" or reducing can be single {date:number} or complex document with multiple {date1:number, date2: number, ... }